# why does console.log get populated with (innerhtml) content in the 1st for loop iteration itself immediately

Tags: javascript

```js
let array1 = '{"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
"https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener":"Event listeners"\
}';

const obj121 = JSON.parse(array1);

for (let key in obj121) {
  d1 = document.createElement('div');
  d1.setAttribute('id', obj121[key]);
  console.log(d1);
  d1.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj121[key]}</a>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_flexx').append(d1);
}
```

```css
.my_flexx {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my_flexx"></h1>
```

when `for` lop runs for the 1st iteration , [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpTWL.png) prints the value `<a href="https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started">React Start</a>` which seems incorrect to me. Should this value not get bypassed for the 1st `for` loop iteration as the code `console.log(d1);` comes first and then
`d1.innerHTML=`${obj121[key]}`;`

please explain

Comment: Aside: you're adding `div` elements to a heading (`h1`) element. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: I didnt know this concept, please provide a MDN quote/doc so that I can read further

Comment: See the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) under "permitted content".

Comment: ` for (let key in obj121) {
  d1 = document.createElement('div');
  d1.setAttribute('id', obj121[key]);
  console.log(d1);
  d1.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj121[key]}</a>`;
  document.querySelector('.my_flexx').append(d1);
} ` so for the 1st `for` loop iteration the   code `console.log(d1);` executes before the code `  d1.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj121[key]}</a>`;`

Comment: hence for the 1st iteration d1.innerHTML hasnt been set but in console.log it gets populated ?..thats the problem

Comment: in Microsoft Edge version 112 console.log can you see ```<div id="React Start"><a href="https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started">React Start</a></div>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `console.log` an object (like `HTMLElement`) its inner properties are evaluated on its current state. Not like a snapshot. So by the time you click on it to expand it, the `innerHTML` of it is already set.

Checkout the tooltip - I have `console.log(window)`:

[image]

You can print a string `element.outerHTML` instead just to to ensure things still make sense.

Comment: I am trying to search in MS Edge console.log something similar in above snapshoot 'this value was evaluated upon first expanding.It may have changed since then' .Can you find something similar text?

Comment: Edge has the same feature and tooltip (not necessarily had to be so)

Comment: please provide the tooltip/snapshot..thanks

Comment: It's literally the same. Expand the object then you will see an icon which has this tooltip